# Powershell concatenation order with function variables and literals

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation

I'm not sure if I am completely mad or missing something but I am trying to do something very simple which is pipe separate a load of variables in a function and write them out.

"Easy" you say? I would have thought so. But here is a wee extract of my attempts to write a powehell function to make the rest of my code a little easier on the eye.

```
$logtoFile=$false
function logEntry($entryType, $section, $message)
{

    #The way I assumed woudl work
    $logString1 = $(get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "|" + $entryType + "|" + $section + "|" + $message
    #Another way which should also work
    $logString2 = "$(get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")|$entryType|$section|$message"
    #Proof that it is not the pipes causing issues
    $logString3 = "$(get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),$entryType,$section,$message"
    #another method I found. Not sure what the issue is there
    $logString4 = $(get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"), $entryType, $section, $message -join "|"
    $WhatIwant = $(get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "|0|moonin|plimsole"

    if($script:logtoFile)
    {
        Add-Content $logFile $logString
    }
    else
    {
        write-host $logString1
        write-host $logString2
        write-host $logString3
        write-host $logString4
        write-host $whatIwant
    }
}
logEntry(0,"moomin","plimsole")
```

Output:

```
2011-02-17 11:22:59|System.Object[]||
2011-02-17 11:22:59|0 moomin plimsole||
2011-02-17 11:22:59,0 moomin plimsole,,
2011-02-17 11:22:59|0 moomin plimsole||
2011-02-17 11:22:59|0|moonin|plimsole
```

Searching around I found several alternatives, none of which seem to produce the right results. I'm not sure what the whole "lump all of the variables together space separated" thing as all about in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function incorrectly.  You are putting 0, mommin, and plimsole into the first variable, and nothing for the second and third variables.  Hence, the output you are getting.

Instead of calling the function like this

```
logEntry(0,"moomin","plimsole")
```

You need to call the function like this

```
logEntry 0 "moomin" "plimsole"
```

Comment: I was posting this but you beat me.  With that change, all but the third approach give the expected results.

Comment: I forgot comments couldn't have carriage return and submitted early. Thanks for that. It never even occured to me to check the function calling syntax sunce that's the way it is in everything else I have been using for years. No wonder there was nothing on the concatenation issue since there actually was none.

Answer (score 1):

Classic PowerShell misunderstanding. You call functions just like you call cmdlets - space separated arguments instead of comma separated e.g.:

```
logEntry 0 moomin plimsole
```

Comment: Come'on SO, you were supposed to let me know if an answer was already posted.  :-)

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the first and will not be the last. Here's one more place where someone looking for the answer to completely the wrong question will find the answer to the right one. Still "How many roads must a man walk down?" sounds good to me even if it was a mouse who suggested it.